# Asp .net Session state to true causing requesting queuing at the server end with same user

Tags: asp.net, session

In my web application user can run reports, which are having large amount of data , so it is taking much time to execute.

In my run report page i have set the session state to true and i am writing to session variable during report generation , so at the same time if user wants to navigate to other page he has to wait for navigation, because lock is kept by run report page. so when run report page is completely executed then only user gets it navigated page.

It means there are request queuing if session is locked by any page (Writing to session).

I can not change the session state to read only.

Any suggestion from any one to solve this problem.

Code snippet

In page1.aspx

```
Session["Test"] ="testing...";

// Some long running code

for(int i=0;i<10000000000000;i++)
{

}
```

Now user wants to go page2.aspx during long running code
    then in page2.aspx i am getting

```
Response.Write(Session["Test"]);

to null
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like a bit more information on your reports. Is there a reason you store them in a Session item?

Comment: yes there are some data which are continuously updating session variable

Comment: I don't know how your software is built, but is it possible to load the data asynchronously via UpdatePanel ?

Comment: @UwConcept When u set session mode in any page to true the your page takes a writer lock on it,  other pages have to wait for reading from or writing  to session variable. it means same user with two current request has to wait. this is my problem

Comment: I'm not judging or criticising, but from the looks of it you've created a very nasty bottleneck. The session variable is continuously updated, but all other requests have to wait for the update to be completed. Is there a way you can perform the data manipulation at the database side in a stored procedure?

Comment: @UwConcept each page takes a session lock until it completely executed whether page is using or not session variables. in my case page has long process , so until page in not completely executed  other requests from same session id in different tab has to wait.